# Логика расположения изображений в коллаже

Tags: jquery, алгоритм, вёрстка, css, javascript

Пишу свой [коллаж](https://github.com/killbond/collage) (пытаюсь). Что он делает - располагает изображения на странице таким образом:

[image]

Однако, из примера очевидно, что возможен кейс, когда изображение будет слишком большим по высоте, как в примере 510 пикселей, и было бы не логично размещать такое высокое изображение не единственным в колонке и, к сожалению, мне в голову не приходит мысли, каков должен быть алгоритм проработки подобных случаев (расположить слишком высокие изображения единственными в своей колонке). Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как быть в этом случае? Существует ли элегантное решение?

[Пример на фиддле](http://jsfiddle.net/bk6C9/2/), однако плагин в таком окружении начинает работать почему-то только при ресайзе страницы.

ЗЫ: да коллажей много на просторах интернета, но в моем случае колонка не может быть фиксированной ширины и заранее неизвестно, сколько должно быть колонок. Готовых решений, удовлетворяющих этим условиям, я не нашел. (прибавил работы дизайнер)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на этот [плагин](http://modx.im/blog/triks/719.html) и [логику](http://ilyaut.ru/addons/gallery-in-the-style-of-vk-or-yandex-kartinki/). По сути ваш случай, кроме расположения элементов.

Comment: Изображения в пределах одной колонки должны быть одинаковой ширины, иначе плагином подгоняем этот параметр до нужного. Т.е. изображение не может занимать часть или более соседней колонки (по ширине), однако может занимать часть или более соседней строки (по высоте).

Comment: После ресайза изображений отсортируйте их по высоте большее-меньшее, распихайте по колонкам, высчитывая каждую итерацию высоту всех изображений в каждой и выбирав колонку с наименьшей общей высотой.